# Search Final Compiled HTML of component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have setup a search service and I am passing through a search string as the user types.  I need to search the final rendered HTML components for this text (after the async pipe; what I see when I am in developer tools).  I am trying to set this as string.  In my component I have the following:

```
import { .. ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ReportsComponent extends HelperGizmoComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
  test;
constructor(..., private el: ElementRef) {
        super();
...
}
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.test = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML.toString();
    }
}
```

The variable {{test}} displays the pre-compiled template that I see in the template file for the component, but I am looking for AFTER it is compiled with all my http calls etc.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up have two separate functions, one where I pass the object into, the other where I pass the service variable that I set in the component.  Here are the methods:

```
    getPropertiesString(obj) {
        this.propertiesArray = (Object as any).values(this);
        this.propertiesArray = this.propertiesArray.filter(prop => typeof prop == 'string');
        this.propertiesArray = this.propertiesArray.filter(prop => !(prop.includes('col-')));
        return this.propertiesArray.toString();
  }
    //Gets all service data values of a component for search/filter
    getServiceStringValue(service){
      service.subscribe(data => data
           .map(data => this.serviceString += (JSON.stringify(data) + "; ")));
      return this.serviceString;
    }
```

I am filtering out some properties that are not relevant to search also.  Then in the component, I am calling the methods like so:

```
    ngOnChanges() {
        this.checkterm(this.searchTerm, this.el, 'reports');
    }    
ngOnInit() {
        this.propertiesString = this.getPropertiesString(this);
        this.serviceString = this.getServiceStringValue(this.policies);
    }
```

Finally, I check the search term against those properties and use markJS to highlight them:

```
    checkterm(term, el, component) {
        if (term) {
          el = el.nativeElement.querySelector('md-card-content').textContent.toLowerCase();
          term = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
          if (this.propertiesString !== undefined && this.serviceString !== undefined) {
              if (this.propertiesString.toLowerCase().includes(term) || this.serviceString.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
                  if (this.propertiesString.toLowerCase().includes(term)) { this.showProperties = true }
                  else { this.showProperties = false; };
                  if (this.serviceString.toLowerCase().includes(term) && el) {
                      if (el.indexOf(term) == -1) {
                          this.showServiceNotice = true;
                      }
                      else {
                          this.showServiceNotice = false;
                      }
                  }

                  this.hasTerm.emit('add.' + component);
              }
              else { this.hasTerm.emit('remove.' + component); }
          }
          else { console.log('services still undefined') }
      }
    }
}
```

On the search page itself where I have added all the components from throughout the app

```
<reports class="srchComp" (hasTerm)="termCallback($event)" [searchTerm]="searchTerm" [hidden]="returnComponents.toString().indexOf('reports') == -1 || searchTerm == '' "></reports>
```

The termCallback event is on the search page TS:

```
termCallback(event) {
    this.arrayAction = event.split('.');
    let test = this.returnComponents.toString().indexOf(this.arrayAction[1]);
    if (this.arrayAction[0] == 'add' && test == -1){
        this.returnComponents.push(this.arrayAction[1]);
    }
    else {
        if (this.arrayAction[0] == 'remove' && test !== -1){
            this.returnComponents = this.returnComponents.filter(item => item !== this.arrayAction[1]);
        }
        else {  }
    }
}
```

The search service is just a typical search service where you subscribe to the input using FormBuilder and valueChanges.subscribe.

I suppose it must be odd to search components themselves in an app, as this didn't get any responses.  However, this was my solution, so hopefully it helps somebody, and if anybody comes across this and has any other questions please let me know.